# Asp.net MVC3 DropdownList Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, html-select

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; } 
    //or
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; } 
}
```

Controller:

```
ViewBag.Categories = db.Categories.ToList();
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId , new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories , "CategoryId ", "Title"),"")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId )
```

And I Have Client Side Validation

But in Microsoft Default Scaffolding :

Controller:

```
ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId ", "Title");
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId" ,"")
```

It is Very Nice And clean Code. but client side validation dont work. How Can I use Microsoft default scaffolding syntax and I have Client side Validation

Answer (score 0):

Just make you CategoryId Property nullable

```
[Required]
public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
```